# Starting a local Service from different processes of same application

Tags: android, android-service

I found the following snippets in the Android docs.

```
 A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process...
```

and

```
 Note that calls to startService() are not nesting: no matter how many times you call startService(), a single call to stopService(Intent) will stop it.
```

I believe this means that multiple calls to startService() does not result in multiple instances of the Service.

Consider the following scenario:

I have an app called `MyApp` which contains two Services: `MyService` and `MyRemoteService`. Here, MyService is a **local** Service while, as the name suggests, MyRemoteService **runs in a separate process**.

What would happen if I were to call `startService()` to start `MyService` from the main `Activity` of `MyApp` and then also from `MyRemoteService`?

Which process will MyService then run in? Will there be two different instances of MyService running in the two different processes: one in the process hosting my main Activity, and the other instance in the process hosting MyRemoteService? How would the above two snippets hold up in such a scenario? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "What if I call startService() to start MyService from my main Activity and then also from a remote Service MyRemoteService (running in a separate process)?" -- I would recommend that you substantially expand this description. Your overall question hinges on this description, and as it stands, I have no idea whether how many apps are involved. For example, is `Activity` and `MyService` in the same app? Is `MyRemoteService` in the same app as are `Activity` and `MyService`? And so on.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've edited my question with necessary clarification.

Comment: "Will there be two different instances of MyService running in the two different processes: one in the process hosting my main Activity, and the other instance in the process hosting MyRemoteService?" -- that would be my gut instinct, though I have never tried this scenario.

Comment: I feel the same but I was hoping that there would be a single instance of the service. Man I'm finding synchronization across different processes a pain in the butt.

Comment: "I was hoping that there would be a single instance of the service" -- that should be possible, but it will require both services to use AIDL. IOW, there is no "local" and no "remote" service; they are both equally "remote". It is merely a question of which process they run in.

Comment: I cannot pass a Lock implementation using AIDL. I need a service that doesn't have to use AIDL so that I can use a ReentrantLock object between the service and the main Activity.